# Should this rolling resistance formula be scaled based on wheel count?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I found two websites that model the power required to overcome the losses due to rolling resistance when riding a bike, [here](https://www.trainingpeaks.com/blog/understanding-rolling-resistance/) and [here](https://blog.flocycling.com/aero-wheels/why-rolling-resistance-makes-you-slower-the-faster-you-go/).
Both of them give the same formula for the Power (ignoring the gradient term in the first link, which is 1 for a flat road),

$$ P_{rr} = C_{rr}mgv $$

That equations seems reasonable given that $C_{rr}$ is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance) as $F_{rr} = C_{rr}N = C_{rr}mg$, and $P=Fv$.

But link #2 seems to suggest that this will calculate the power required to overcome the resistance of *just one wheel*, and so to get the total result we must multiply by 2.

Link #1 doesn't seem to include this in the calculation.

So my question is : **Do we need to multiply by the number of wheels**?

Intuitively to me, I assumed that the *m* in the equation above was the mass of the system (bike + rider). Surely if you multiply the value by 2, you're compensating for the fact that each wheel takes approximately (very approximately I would guess) half the load of the system.

Comment: mg is the weight supported by the wheel. If mg is the total weight of the bike +rider, each wheel supports mg/2.

Comment: @BobD that's what I figured, from which I drew the conclusion that Link 2 is incorrect, since they are using the full weight of the system for the calculation and then doubling the result by 2. It makes sense to me that you double the result when using half the total weight, or don't double and use the full weight.

Comment: What specific part of link 2?

Comment: After the 9.24W calculation, they mention that this is "only for one tire" [here](https://blog.flocycling.com/aero-wheels/why-rolling-resistance-makes-you-slower-the-faster-you-go/#:~:text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%209.24W%20would%20be%20consumed%20by%20rolling%20resistance%20in%20this%20example.%20Remember%20this%20is%20only%20for%20one%20tire%2C%20so%20we%20need%20to%20double%20this%20value%20for%20total%20watt%20consumption%20due%20to%20rolling%20resistance.)

Comment: Doesn’t make sense to me